# For non-constant polynomial $f(t)$, there is a linear transformation $T$ such that $\phi_T(t) = (-1)^n f(t)$

Tags: linear-algebra, characteristic-polynomial

I want to prove the following theorem

Let $f(t)$ be a non-constant monic polynomial of degree $n$. Then there exists a linear operator $T$ on $n-$dimensional space $V$ with the characteristic polynomial $\phi_T(t)= (-1)^n f(t)$.

---

How one can prove this? I know characteristic polynomial of a linear operator $T$ is given $\phi_T(t)=\det(T-t I)$ and since $T$ is $n\times n$ matrix it has the form of $(-1)^n (t^n+ \cdots)$, so Naively for any linear operator $T$ I can find the non-constant monic polynomial of degree $n$.

Is my approach valid?

Comment: HAve you seen: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form

Comment: What field are you working with?

Comment: The keyword is "companion matrix"

Comment: @GreginGre Nice, I thought it will be messy if the field isn't algebraically closed, but it's actually still quite simple.